# Remix IDE - transact to ___ errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Tags: remix, gas, out-of-gas, gas-limit

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Testing {

  address public owner;

  function Testing() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function() public payable {
  }

  function withdrawAll() public  {
    uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
    owner.transfer(balance);
  }

}
```

#### 47s video: https://youtu.be/HpDUE3_NGBw

> transact to Testing.withdrawAll errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bug in testrpc

It appears to be a bug when using remix with testrpc.

Please see this issue:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/447

The bug is fixed in version 7 of ganache.

To install this version, use:

```
npm install -g ganache-cli@7.0.0-beta.0
```

The contract itself is correct, as using the javascript VM, this contract works properly.

[image: run.gif]

Comment: Using `testrpc`, blocks are mined immediately, I think the video shows that previous transaction has been mined.

Comment: I don't think you're right about that... try using the javascript VM, I've attached a demo where I'm using it and it works fine. Can you check that owner is returning correctly when you click it.

Comment: Found out there's a bug in ganache. Appears to be fixed in the latest beta version.

Comment: OK, let me reinstall `testrpc` aka `ganache`. In the meanwhile, transaction with gas price `1000 gwei` is pending on Ropsten: https://imgur.com/a/hbnyv

Comment: I just installed `Ganache CLI v7.0.0-beta.0 (ganache-core: 3.0.0-beta.0)` and tested and it seems to work.

Comment: `npm install -g ganache-cli@v7.0.0-beta.0` - now the code automagically works... Estimated time debugging: `3-4 hours`. Energy expense, frustration, losing sanity, demotivation: `ridiculous`. Now pay me some ETH... Thank you for helping!

Comment: @norganna My ganache is still using its old cli how I can link `ganache-cli@v7.0.0-beta.0` with ganache?