# "Out of Gas" while transferring ethereum from account to contract

Tags: gas, ganache, gas-limit

I am using ganache to create 10 ethereum accounts. I want to transfer ethereum from one account to a smart contract. I am doing this by writing two following smart contracts in solidity;

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
contract Ether_Transfer_To{
    function () external payable { //fallback function

    }
    function get_balance() public returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
contract Ether_Transfer_From{
    Ether_Transfer_To private the_instance;
    constructor() public{
        //the_instance=Ether_Transfer_To(address(this));
        the_instance=new Ether_Transfer_To();
    }
    function get_balance() public returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function get_balance_of_instance() public returns(uint){
        //return address(the_instance).balance;
        return the_instance.get_balance();
    }
    function () external payable {
        // msg.sender.send(msg.value)
        address(the_instance).send(msg.value);
    }
}
```

When I deploy the `contract Ether_Transfer_From` smart contract then I get its three-member functions as follows in remix;

[image]

But when I sent one 1 Wei from account to smart contract by writing 1 in the text box and clicking on a (fallback) button, then I get the following error;

> transact to Ether_Transfer_From. (fallback) errored: VM Exception while
>   processing transaction: out of gas

I followed the answer of the same [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/remix-ide-transact-to-errored-vm-exception-while-processing-transaction) by installing `Ganache-cli 7.0.0 beta.0` by using following command;

> npm install -g ganache-cli@7.0.0-beta.0

But I still get the same error. I think I am using older Ganache cli instead of `Ganache-cli 7.0.0 beta.0` as it goes to C drive and I installed `ganache 2.1.1` in D drive previously.

I just want to send ethereum from one account to other but I am really stuck in this `out of gas` Error. If there is any way to remove this error or transfer ethereum from one account to another then please let me know.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Remix, using the JavaScript VM and Solidity compiler version `0.5.11+commit.c082d0b4`, so presumably the issue is with Ganache.

Comment: Yes i know that there is issue with Ganache. Is there any way to fix that issue or tranfer  the ether using any other method?

Comment: Did you figure this out? Please share the solution, I'm stuck on the same point.

Comment: @Surinderkumar I also posted the same issue on Github. It was a problem with `Ganache`. But the fixed it in the later version. 
Please make sure you have the latest version of `Ganache` & `Ganache-core`. Also, you should use the newer `Remix` interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I am running txs on live ethereum and facing this issue.